# Load css file from assets using stylePreprocessorOptions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have created a folder for CSS files inside my assets directory. I have also added stylePreprocessorOptions in my angular.json. When I am trying to import the css file I keep getting the error that it is not being found.

If I import directly like `@import './assets/css/icons.css';` then angular no complaining

I have tried different paths like this but nothing worked `"src/assets/styles"`, `"/assets/styles",`

styles.css:

```
@import 'icons.css';
```

Angular Json:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "switch-candidate": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "css",
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:application": {
                    "strict": true,
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:resolver": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:directive": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:guard": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:service": {
                    "skipTests": true
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/switch-candidate",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": ["src/assets/css"]
                        },
                        "scripts": [],
                        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["crypto-js"]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                                    "maximumError": "1mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                                    "maximumError": "4kb"
                                }
                            ],
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputHashing": "all"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "buildOptimizer": false,
                            "optimization": false,
                            "vendorChunk": true,
                            "extractLicenses": false,
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "namedChunks": true
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "switch-candidate:build:production"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "browserTarget": "switch-candidate:build:development"
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "switch-candidate:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just import the css inside the `angular.json` it will be the same as doing it inside styles.css

Also note to my knowledge you cannot import multiple styles like a glob pattern, instead create a single file called `index.css` and then import all the files using that single file!

```
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                "options": {
                    "outputPath": "dist/switch-candidate",
                    "index": "src/index.html",
                    "main": "src/main.ts",
                    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                    "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                    "styles": [
                        "src/styles.css",
                        "assets/css/icons.css",
                    ],
```